# Como crear evento para una class en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, eventos, class

tengo la necesitad de crear un evento que se ejecuta al cambiar las propiedades de 3 objetos que tengo en una clase. Para poder presentar todo debo enseñarles lo que tengo hecho:
A continuación la clase completa, la cual su función es crear en un `ToolStrip` un filtro de búsqueda por `fecha` donde se puede elegir, una fecha, entre dos fechas o bien siempre, y es la siguiente:

```
Public Class filtrofecha
    Implements IDisposable

    Private labelfiltroporfecha As ToolStripLabel
    Public Property hora1 As New DateTime
    Public Property hora2 As New DateTime
    Public Property tipodeintervalo As New intervalo
    Public Enum intervalo
        porfecha 
        porintervalo 
        todoeltiempo
    End Enum
    Private horas1lab As Label
    Private horas2lab As Label
    Public horas1 As DateTimePicker
    Public horas2 As DateTimePicker
    Public tiempo As ComboBox
    Private barraaagregar As ToolStrip
    Private barra As ToolStripControlHost

    Sub New(ByRef barraaagregar0 As ToolStrip, ByRef horas01 As DateTimePicker, ByRef horas02 As DateTimePicker, ByRef tiempo0 As ComboBox)
        barraaagregar = barraaagregar0
        horas1 = horas01
        horas2 = horas02
        horas1lab = New Label
        horas2lab = New Label
        tiempo = tiempo0
        labelfiltroporfecha = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLabel()
        labelfiltroporfecha.Name = "labelfiltroporfecha"
        labelfiltroporfecha.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(94, 24)
        labelfiltroporfecha.Text = "Filtro de tiempo:"
        horas1lab.Text = "Desde:"
        horas2lab.Text = "Hasta:"
        horas1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short
        horas2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short
        horas1.Width = 85
        horas2.Width = 85
        horas1.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        horas2.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        tiempo.Items.Add("Fecha")
        tiempo.Items.Add("Intervalo")
        tiempo.Items.Add("Todo el tiempo")
        tiempo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        barraaagregar.Items.Add(labelfiltroporfecha)
        barra = New ToolStripControlHost(tiempo)
        barraaagregar.Items.Add(barra)
        barra = New ToolStripControlHost(horas1lab)
        barraaagregar.Items.Add(barra)
        barra = New ToolStripControlHost(horas1)
        barraaagregar.Items.Add(barra)
        barra = New ToolStripControlHost(horas2lab)
        barraaagregar.Items.Add(barra)
        barra = New ToolStripControlHost(horas2)
        barraaagregar.Items.Add(barra)
        AddHandler tiempo.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf TiempoSelectedIndexChanged
        AddHandler horas1.ValueChanged, AddressOf horas1_ValueChanged
        AddHandler horas2.ValueChanged, AddressOf horas2_ValueChanged
        tiempo.SelectedIndex = 2
    End Sub
    Private Sub compararfechas()
        Me.hora1 = horas1.Value
        Me.hora2 = horas2.Value
        If tiempo.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            If Not (DateTime.Compare(horas1.Value, horas2.Value) > 0) Then
                mensaje("Ingreso de fechas incorrecto!", True)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub horas1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        compararfechas()
    End Sub
    Private Sub horas2_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        compararfechas()
    End Sub
    Sub TiempoSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Select Case tiempo.SelectedIndex
            Case 1
                tipodeintervalo = intervalo.porintervalo
                horas2.Visible = True
                horas2lab.Visible = True
                horas1lab.Visible = True
                horas1.Visible = True
            Case 0
                tipodeintervalo = intervalo.porfecha
                horas2.Visible = False
                horas2lab.Visible = False
                horas1lab.Visible = True
                horas1.Visible = True
            Case 2
                tipodeintervalo = intervalo.todoeltiempo
                horas2.Visible = False
                horas2lab.Visible = False
                horas1.Visible = False
                horas1lab.Visible = False
        End Select
    End Sub

#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Private disposedValue As Boolean ' Para detectar llamadas redundantes

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                ' TODO: elimine el estado administrado (objetos administrados).
            End If

            ' TODO: libere los recursos no administrados (objetos no administrados) y reemplace Finalize() a continuación.
            ' TODO: configure los campos grandes en nulos.
        End If
        disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    ' TODO: reemplace Finalize() solo si el anterior Dispose(disposing As Boolean) tiene código para liberar recursos no administrados.
    'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    '    ' No cambie este código. Coloque el código de limpieza en el anterior Dispose(disposing As Boolean).
    '    Dispose(False)
    '    MyBase.Finalize()
    'End Sub

    ' Visual Basic agrega este código para implementar correctamente el patrón descartable.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' No cambie este código. Coloque el código de limpieza en el anterior Dispose(disposing As Boolean).
        Dispose(True)
        ' TODO: quite la marca de comentario de la siguiente línea si Finalize() se ha reemplazado antes.
        ' GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region
End Class
```

Aquí las propiedades que quiero importa seria `Hora1` y `Hora2` que son `Datetime`, y `tipodeintervalo` que es un objeto `Enumerable` personalizado. El evento a crear es cuando se cambia los valores de estas propiedades

A continuación el código de como creo un objeto de esta clase:

```
Private filtroitemsanulados As filtrofecha
 Dim tiempofiltro As New ComboBox
                AddHandler tiempofiltro.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf fitroanulaciones
                Dim horas1filtro As New DateTimePicker
                AddHandler horas1filtro.ValueChanged, AddressOf fitroanulaciones
                Dim horas2filtro As New DateTimePicker
                AddHandler horas2filtro.ValueChanged, AddressOf fitroanulaciones
                filtroitemsanulados = New filtrofecha(Barradeitemsanulados, horas1filtro, horas2filtro, tiempofiltro)
```

Aquí los eventos por defecto de `Valuechanged` y `SelectedIndexChanged` de los parámetros de `horas1filtro`, `horas2filtro` y `tiempofiltro` son algo parecido a lo que busco, el problema con esto es que las propiedades anteriormente dichas no se modifican en estos eventos, sino unos milisegundos luego. Es decir que no me sirven, por ejemplo al cambiar el índice de combo box de `tiempofiltro` cambia el índice pero lo que sucede en la clase en el mismo evento es lo siguiente, cito código:

```
Sub TiempoSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Select Case tiempo.SelectedIndex
            Case 1
                tipodeintervalo = intervalo.porintervalo
                horas2.Visible = True
                horas2lab.Visible = True
                horas1lab.Visible = True
                horas1.Visible = True
            Case 0
                tipodeintervalo = intervalo.porfecha
                horas2.Visible = False
                horas2lab.Visible = False
                horas1lab.Visible = True
                horas1.Visible = True
            Case 2
                tipodeintervalo = intervalo.todoeltiempo
                horas2.Visible = False
                horas2lab.Visible = False
                horas1.Visible = False
                horas1lab.Visible = False
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Como se puede ver, el `tipodeintervalo`, cambia de valor luego de pasar por esta `sub`. Lo que deseo es crear un evento tal como lo siguiente:

```
Private filtroitemsanulados As filtrofecha
Dim tiempofiltro As New ComboBox                    
Dim horas1filtro As New DateTimePicker
Dim horas2filtro As New DateTimePicker
filtroitemsanulados = New filtrofecha(Barradeitemsanulados, horas1filtro, horas2filtro, tiempofiltro)
AddHandler filtroitemanulados.cambianpropiedades, AddresOf Rellenado
```

Entonces cuando voy a dicha `sub` tendría algo tal que así:

```
Sub rellenado ()
'alguno de los siguientes cambian
msgbox(filtroitemsanulados.hora1.tostring) <--- con hora cambiada
msgbox(filtroitemsanulados.hora2.tostring) <--- con hora cambiada
msgbox(filtroitemsanulados.tipodeintervalo.tostring) <--- con variable ambiada
end sub
```

En esta ultima solo se mostrara por pantalla las variables, lo interesante seria que se mueren los cambios ni bien son realizados por el usuario.
Espero haberme explicado bien! GRACIAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude encontrar la forma de solucionarlo, lo primero es crear un evento con esta simple línea

```
Public Event cambiolaspropiedades()
```

Luego, a la clase ya asignada este evento, al crear una instancia de esta clase se puede invocar el evento a un procedimiento

En la misma clase para invocar al evento es con la siguiente línea

```
RaiseEvent cambiolaspropiedades()
```

Está línea la coloco siempre luego de asignar un valor a la propiedad y listo, espero que a quien encuentre está pregunta Le sea de ayuda!!